# System.TypeException: System.runAs can only be used with an active user

Tags: apex, unit-test, cicd, deployment-error

I am trying to deploy one UserStory from UAT to Prod in Copado, but receiving this error "System.TypeException: System.runAs can only be used with an active user" for one Test class.
But i haven't added this class in UserStory.
May i please know how to deploy to prod now?
[image]

Comment: Don't know anything about Copado, but the error message in the title could be avoided by adding `IsActive = true` to the where clause of the `User` query.

Comment: Also See all data is bad, you must create your own test data and write test with it.

Answer (score 2):

The solution here appears to be glaringly obvious. The error message spells it out for you. The user you're using with `System.runAs()` is not active, and that method requires an active user.

So you need to give it an active user. Simple as that.

Including the `IsActive = true` filter in the `WHERE` clause of your query on `User` as Keith C mentioned in the comments will ensure that you can only get an active user back from that query.

Of course, the "best practice" here would be to create a test user in the unit test (or more generally, somewhere in the test class) itself so that you aren't relying on data that may be present in one org but not another.